# How to clear this object is possibly null error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am now testing the `firebase.auth().currentUser` I am expecting sometimes it can be null.

```
export type AppState = {
  readonly labs: {
    [labId: string]: LabState;
  };
  readonly labUi: LabUiState;
  readonly editor: EditorState;
  readonly firebase?: FirebaseReducer.Reducer<{}>;
};

 export const loadState = (): AppState => {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val() as AppState;
      });
  }
};
```

As you can see i am testing if there is a user. if user i am doing something.
but the typescript is giving me these problems alert. Is there anything wrong with what i am doing right now?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see i am testing if there is a user...

You're testing if the `.uid` property of `currentUser` is falsy, but the error is telling you that a value (presumably `currentUser`) may be `null`.

So there are two things to do:

1. Check `currentUser`, not a property on it (or possibly both); and
2. Put `currentUser` into a constant before checking it, so TypeScript knows it's okay to narrow the type of that value.

Along these lines:

```typescript
export const loadState = (): AppState => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    if (currentUser) {
        let userId = currentUser.uid;
        return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            return snapshot.val() as AppState;
        });
    }
};
```

Or since you already have a `userId` variable, perhaps with optional chaining (`?.`):

```typescript
export const loadState = (): AppState => {
    const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid;
    if (userId) {
        return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            return snapshot.val() as AppState;
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , 
If you don't mind. Do you know why this error also occuring?
`Type 'Promise<AppState>' is missing the following properties from type 'AppState': labs, labUi, editor`

Comment: @Kerry - Your function returns a promise, not an `AppState`. Actually it returns a promise *or* `undefined`, which I would suggest changing. But in its current form, its return type should be `Promise<AppState> | undefined`, not just `AppState`.